# Difference between alloy widgets and titanium modules..

Tags: titanium, titanium-modules

what is the Difference between alloy widgets and titanium modules.. ? and when to use what..

Answer (score 0):

Alloy, a model-view-controller (MVC) framework for Titanium.where as modules in not mvc both can be used anywhere there is no much difference . but alloys is new  MVC Framework .Where you can Devlop app more rapid than the later. Alloys are used to create some widgets and some other extra stuff . to make your App more Interactive,Fun ,and Good..

Alloy is a “component-oriented” application framework that enforces separation of concerns with a Model/View/Controller architecture. Let’s take a look at some of the core architectural concepts for Alloy.

you can folllow this [link](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/11/gtka-one.html)

Comment: thanks sundar.. i understood wat u said abt MVC.. but within an alloy project, when shud i use widgets and when modules?

Comment: widget are like plugin ... you can create different widget of different functionality and use then when you need in your app..but modules are old ...u can use both anywhere ..but alloys are now best and lot of research is going on ..one example u need to show time in ur app . u can create widget for time and include that in app .. table view etcs ..

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but... this is the first hit when Googling "titanium modules widgets," so... I'm guessing a lot of people don't know.

Here is Appcelerator's explanation of modules:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Using_Modules

And here is it's explanation of widgets:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Widgets

Biggest difference to me? Modules are old, widgets are new. Widgets include Alloy's XML and TSS structure. Use a module if you can't find a widget to your liking. Make widgets.